# C# source code compilation from command line (any cases, without Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, dll, cmake, compilation, msbuild

Dear Community. I have faced on the case when is needed to compile C# source code without **Visual Studio** usage in order to build it in DLL library and then include this package into other platforms (not only Windows-based). After a little bit of investigation **CMake** as a build tool has been chosen and appropriate configuration file (**CMakeLists.txt**) created. During it's running using native command prompt there is a mistake of compilation - "**C# is currently only supported for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and later**". That's why I would like to ask you share your knowledge and provide any additional cases to build it (some additional tools or whole scenarios) such as I'm a brand new in this topic and can't proceed before that wall (; . Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it's a .Net Core or .Net 5, you don't need VS, just dotnet cli

Comment: Agreed with @Magnetron . Use dotnet core or .net 5. this might help get you started: https://maniuk.medium.com/cross-compiling-dotnet-core-for-linux-3d13c2be501d

Comment: Since you explicitly say "not only Windows-based" you must be using .NET Core or newer (that includes .NET 5, but not .NET 4.x), even if unknowingly so ;-). Therefore, as others have commented, install the [.NET SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) and [have go](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/install). No need for Visual Studio, all necessary stuff is included. Albeit you might consider using [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) - which is free and cross platform - as well.